# Skip wrapper on associations with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using simple_form, and I wonder if it's possible to skip any wrapper divs when dealing with an association select.

Thank's

Comment: have you tried? if so, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to use some options like `wrapper_html: false`, but i still get some divs that i cannot remove

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using something like `f.association :product` you can remove both the generated label and wrapper like so: `f.association :product, label: false, wrapper: false`

Comment: hitham-s-alqadheeb answer is the correct one.  Use f.input_field.

Comment: @hellion This question is specifically asking about associations so I'd argue that this answer may be a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs

> SimpleForm also allows you to strip away all the div wrappers around
>   the  field that is generated with the usual f.input. The
>   easiest way to achieve this is to use f.input_field.

Example:

```
simple_form_for @user do |f|
  f.input_field :name
end
```

Produces:

```
<input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="100"
   name="user[name]" size="100" type="text" value="Carlos" />
```

To view the actual RDocs for this, check them out here - http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field

**Or ...**

Do something like

```
config.wrappers :small do |b|
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label_input
end
```

and use it in this way:

```
# Specifying to whole form
simple_form_for @user, wrapper: :small do |f|
  f.input :name
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#configuration

Comment: Is there a way to specify it for only one association?

Comment: I know you can pass params to it, not sure different ones for the same form.  What I would do is actually leave them all wrapped in a div, but customize my divs with CSS.  You can make a div not be a div with CSS.  Also, check this comment "SimpleForm also allows you to strip away all the div wrappers around the <input> field that is generated with the usual `f.input`. The easiest way to achieve this is to use `f.input_field`."

Answer (score 1):

use [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) instead, in haml:

```
= f.collection_select :position_id, Position.all, :id, :name, {}, { class: 'span3' }
```

this example assumes you have a position model and want to add `span3` as a class on the `<select>` it generates